# non-trivial example of : $f: S \to \Bbb R^+$, $S$ compact, $f$ unbounded, $X_n$ Markov $\in S$ such that $\sup_n f(X_n(\omega)) < M(\omega)$

Tags: probability-theory

I am interested in knowing non-trivial example of the following case: $f: S \to \Bbb R^+$ with $S$ compact, $f$ unbounded, $X_n$ a a Markov process taking values in $S$ such that $\sup_n f(X_n(\omega)) < M(\omega)$. Here $M:\Omega \to \Bbb R^+$ is unbounded

I have a trivial example in mind.
Take $S = [0,1]$, $f(x) = 1/x, x\neq 0$ and $=0$ when $x=0$. $X_n (\omega) =\omega$ with $\Omega = [0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to consider examples with locally compact $S$ (because then we can take the one-point compactification and define $f$ arbitrarily at the extra point).

Let $S=\Bbb Z$ and let $(X_n)$ be the Markov Chain on $\Bbb Z$ starting at $0$ with transition matrix $P(n,n+1)=p$ and $P(n,n-1)=1-p$. We assume $p>1/2$. Let $f(n) = \big( \frac{1-p}{p} \big)^n$.

Note that $(X_n)$ is a transient Markov Chain with $X_n \to +\infty$ a.s. (this can be proved by directly computing $\sum_n P(X_{2n}=0)$). From this it follows that $\inf_n X_n>-\infty$, and thus $\sup_n f(X_n)< \infty$ almost surely. It follows that $(f(X_n))_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is a bounded sequence with probability $1$, but this bound is clearly not absolute since there is a nonzero probability that the sample path reaches large negative values.

**Remark:** The reason that this example is meaningful is because $f$ is actually a $P$-harmonic function and hence $f(X_n)$ is actually a martingale converging to $0$. So, by using the optional stopping theorem, it is actually possible to compute the law of $\inf_n X_n$ and also of the minimal random variable $M$ satisfying the hypothesis of your question.

Comment: Can you please give me a reference for this "$f$ is actually a $P$-harmonic function and hence $f(X_n)$ is actually a martingale converging to $0$"

Comment: Yeah, so what it means to be a $P$-harmonic function is that $Pf=f$, in other words $\sum_y P(x,y)f(y) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in the state space. There is a theorem that states that for a Markov Chain $(X_n)$ with transition matrix $P$, it is true that $f(X_n)$ is a martingale if and only if $f$ is a $P$-harmonic function. The result is easy to prove in discrete-time, it is just a direct computation. An analagous result is also true for continuous-time Markov Processes, see Theorem 1.16 in these notes: https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Anton_Bovier/lecture-notes/markov.pdf